# detect if text inside element already reaches the max-width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my **HTML** code:

```
<input type="text" class="testinput">
<span class="output-text"></span>
```

and I have my **CSS**:

```
.output-text {
     max-width:300px;
}
```

then my **jQuery**

```
$(".testinput").keyup(function(){
     var text = $(this).val();
     $(".output-text").text(text);
});
```

I want to know while I am typing on `input`, it checks the length of text every `keyup` but I want to know when it already reaches `max-width` of the `.output-text` by sending `alert("success");`

Comment: You didn't try anything?

Comment: When accepting an answer below, consider using `keydown` instead of `keyup`. Because keyup will trigger only when the button is release, it won't fire your alert until the button is release, so the width can pass a lot from the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, Use an input type text and past the content into an invisible div.

```js
var inputElem = document.getElementById('input'),
  fakeElem = document.getElementById('fakeElem');

inputElem.oninput = function() {
  fakeElem.innerText = inputElem.value;
  if(fakeElem.clientWidth > 300) {
    alert('Hi');
  }
}
```

```css
#fakeElem {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<input id='input' type='text'>
<div id='fakeElem'></div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the text inside `DIV` is the same font that's used inside `input`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(".testinput").keyup(function(){
 var text = $(this).val();

 if($('.output-text').width() > parseInt($(".output-text").css('max-width'))) { //your max-width
    alert('success');
 }

 $(".output-text").text(text);
});
```

Please do note that `$(".output-text").css('max-width')` returns a string of the value plus the measurement units, so it will return the string `'300px'` `'100vw'` or `'100%'`. The code above will not work if you have percentage based values, viewport values, or calculated values on the CSS.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.width()` to check the width of the span.

```js
var output = $(".output-text");
$(".testinput").keyup(function(){
     var text = $(this).val();
     output.text(text);
     if(output.width()>300){
     //more than max-width 300px
     console.log('Output width has exceeded 300px: '+output.width());
     alert('Success!');
     }
});
```

```css
.output-text {
     max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="testinput">
<span class="output-text"></span>
```